# What happens when JavaScript variable name and function name is the same?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, hoisting, name-binding

I have the following code, where I declare a function and after it, a variable with the same name as the function:

```
function a(x) {
    return x * 2;
}

var a;
alert(a);
```

I expected this to alert `undefined`, but if I run it, the alert will display the following:

> function a(x) {
>       return x * 2
>   }

If I assign  a value to the variable (like `var a = 4`), the alert will display that value (`4`), but without this change `a` will be recognized as a function.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What is it you would expect? Variables and functions share the same namespace in JavaScript, so they override each other.

Comment: @Sirko  I would expect a to be undefined

Comment: if function name and variable name are same then JS Engine ignores the variable.

Comment: With `var a` you create a new variable. The declaration is actually hoisted to the start of the current scope (before the function definition). Afterwards the name is used up by the function of the same name. This is what you get when using `alert()`.

Comment: The engine first hoists variables (to undefined). then it hoists function declarations.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Functions** are a type of **object** which are a type of **value**.

Values can be stored in variables (and properties, and passed as arguments to functions, etc).

**A function declaration:**

- Creates a named function
- Creates a variable in the current scope with the same name as the function (unless such a variable already exists)
- Assigns the function to that variable
- Is hoisted

**A `var` statement:**

- Creates a variable in the current scope with the specified name (unless such a variable already exists)
- Is hoisted
- Doesn't assign a value to that variable (unless combined with an assignment operator)

Both your declaration and `var` statement are hoisted. Only one of them assigns a value to the variable `a`.

Answer (score 20):

In JavaScript both **function declaration** and **variable declarations** are hoisted to the top of the function, if defined in a function, or the top of the global context, if outside a function. And function declaration takes precedence over variable declarations (but not over variable assignment).

**Function Declaration Overrides Variable Declaration When Hoisted**

First you declare a variable:

```
var a; // value of a is undefined
```

Second, the value of `a` is a function because function declaration takes precedence over variable declarations (but not over variable assignment):

```
function a(x) {
  return x * 2;
}
```

And that is what you get when you call `alert(a);`.

But, if instead of declaring a variable you make variable assignment: `var a = 4;` then the assigned value `4` will prevail.

Comment: Function declarations are hoisted too.

Comment: Yes @Quentin but expressions are not or named expressions

Comment: Yes @Quentin: Both function declaration and variable declarations are hoisted to the top of the containing scope. And function declaration takes precedence over variable declarations (but not over variable assignment).

Answer (score 5):

If you use a `function name` as `variable name`, its value is replaced by `function body`. So `var a` becomes your `function a` and thus your alert displays function `a`.

**Edit** But if you assign value to `a` like `var a = "xya";`. Then it `function` will be replaced by `variable`. As per [Order of precedence](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript#toc-order-of-precedence)

1. Variable assignment takes precedence over function declaration
2. Function declarations take precedence over variable declarations

Answer (score 3):

You should also remember that `var a` is hoisted, which makes it more like this

```
var a; // placed

function a(x) {
  return x * 2;
};

var a; // removed
alert (a); // a is replaced by function body
```

Remember that `var a` is hoisted, so if you assign `4 to a`:

```
var a; // placed

function a(x) {
  return x * 2;
};

var a = 4; // removed
a = 4 // added

alert (a); // a is now 4
```

Answer (score 0):

First hoisting takes place. **Function declaration takes precedence over variable declaration during hoisting.**

During execution of the code, if variable is assigned at any point, then it is replaced, otherwise it remains the same function.

(*Note: First read the code from Line 4 to Line 8. Then again read from beginning to end.*)

```
console.log(a); // f a(){...} - Executed just after hoisting
console.log(b); // f b(){...} - Executed just after hoisting

var a = 100; // here variable is assigned
function a(x) {...};

function b(x) {...};
var b; // only a declaration here

console.log(a); // 100
console.log(b); // f b(){...}
```

Answer (score -1):

ES6 comes with a better solution by defining `SyntaxError: Identifier (?) has already been declared` when using `let` / `const` instead of `var`.

`let`

```
function foo () {}
let foo;
// => SyntaxError: Identifier 'foo' has already been declared
```

`const`

```
function foo () {}
const foo = 1;
// => SyntaxError: Identifier 'foo' has already been declared
```

Note that `const foo;` does not work. It will cause `SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration`