# Why am i not getting a type error in the below javaScript function?

Tags: javascript

Shouldn't the value of research be undefined as it has been declared as var research in the end. And hence the output be a type error. But I am getting the output as 'hello'. Any idea why?

```
function newFunc() {
    function research() { console.log('hello') };
    research();
    var research;
}
newFunc();
```

Comment: `var research;` only declares a variable. It doesn’t _set_ it to `undefined`.

Comment: In javascript you can use a variable before it is being declared, so even though it works differently in other programming languages, in js you can declare a variable whenever you prefer (using var) and use it whenever you like: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Comment: Actually when you declare a var. By default undefined gets set. @Sebastian Simon

Comment: My comment was incorrect. `research` is never `undefined`. @Abhishek But here a value is immediately provided at `function research(){`…`}`, so `undefined` is never set.

Comment: See [What happens when JavaScript variable name and function name is the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40675821/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

Because of hoisting, what actually happens is more like this:

```
function newFunc() {
    var research;
    research = function() { console.log('hello') };
    research();        
}
newFunc();
```

Comment: Because of hoisting it changes, I understand. But in the memory allocation phase function declaration is considered and the var declaration is also considered. But since var declaration (var research) is used in the end, the value of research should have been overwritten by undefined.

Comment: Even if that were the case, you're calling the function BEFORE you're declaring it again, so it would only get overwritten after the function call anyway.

Comment: However, I can confirm that that's not the case anyway. `research` still refers to the function even after the `var research;` line

Comment: @Abhishek I’ll rephrase my comment from above: `var research;` never _overwrites_ a variable with `undefined`; it only initializes it when no other value has been provided. But you have to consider that `function research(){}` immediately provides the function as a value, but `var research = function(){};` is split into `var research;` and `research = function(){};`, so it’s `undefined` before only when there is no `function research(){}` in the function scope. The answer is also incorrect.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I guess it makes sense. Since you put it that way. Thanks mate!

Comment: really don't know why this was downvoted - its totally accurate

Comment: @Chev It isn’t. `function` declaration hoisting does not work like it’s shown in this answer. That’s why `(function(){ console.log(x); function x(){} }());` logs the function `x`, whereas `(function(){ console.log(x); var x; x = function(){}; }());` logs `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable declarations and function definitions are [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) - moved to the top of the function scope. So even though you are declaring it at the end, the compiler will move it to the top of the function so it ends up like:

```
function newFunc() {
    var research = function () { console.log('hello') };
    research();
}
newFunc();
```

JS only hoists declarations, not initializations. JS also hoists the actual function definition.

Comment: Even the function declarations are hoisted, is it not?

Comment: Yes, but you are correct, JS also hoists the actual function definition.

Answer (score 0):

> JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

So values will be assigned in the order they are placed, for instance:

```
   x = 2;
   console.log(x);  //2

   x = 3;
   console.log(x);  //3

   var x ;
```

or in your case:

```
   var x = 2;
   console.log(x);  //2

   var x = 3;
   console.log(x);  //3

   var x ;
```

Another thing is that, `research` in the `var research;` part is not undefined; it's rather a function expression till you override it by another assignment, like `var research = '';`

So in your case, it's like the following:

```
function newFunc() {
    function research() { console.log('hello') };
    research(); //'hello'
    var research;
    console.log(research) //function research(){console.log('hello');}
}
```

Comment: _“One more thing, you will never get `TypeError` from assignment”_ — that’s not what the OP claimed. The OP expected a TypeError due to `research` being undefined, when trying to call it, which is never the case.

Comment: @SebastianSimon research has never been `undefined` in the code to start with, next the way I understand it the OP expected `TypeError` because the variable was declared with two different types.

Comment: Even if you set `research` to `undefined`, you will never get `TypeError`. So it's not right to expect `TypeError` in any similar scenario.

Comment: “`research` has never been `undefined`” — that’s what I said: _“a `TypeError` due to research being undefined […], **which is never the case**”_. _“Even if you set `research` to `undefined`, you will never get `TypeError`. So it’s not right to expect `TypeError` in any similar scenario”_ — yes, you _could_ expect one, as I said: _“a `TypeError` due to `research` being `undefined`, **when trying to call it**”_.

Comment: I still didn't get your point clearly. Are you saying if `research` is set to `undefined`, then you will get `typeError` when trying to call it? Okay, to make it simple can you give me a single case where you will get `typeError`? A few line of codes could save a lot of explanation. I really want to update my answer if I posted a wrong information, so I appreciate your comment. Thanks.

Comment: `var research; research();` or `var research = undefined; research();` are obvious examples. The [OP was concerned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58824109/why-am-i-not-getting-a-type-error-in-the-below-javascript-function/58825217#comment103925212_58824170) about the `var research;` at the bottom potentially overwriting the function at the top and make it `undefined`.

Comment: Okay I get your point. Actually, the `TypeError` from your example is from calling the variable not from the assignment. But as you said that may not be what the OP meant. Anyways, I hope the rest part explains why there won't be a `typeError`. I will remove this last part though. Thanks.